# Estou trabahando com bootstrap e meu pull-right não desloca a div nav para a direita?

Tags: html5, bootstrap

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Victor</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <nav id="menu" class="pull-right">
                    <ul>
                        <li>victor</li>
                        <li>victor</li>
                        <li>victor</li>
                        <li>victor</li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>

header{
background-color: #666;
height: 150px;
}
#menu{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Vê se resolve colocando no *css*:

```
menu{
    display: inline-flex;
}
```